# How to get row index from UITableView which the array list made by append to a class

Tags: ios, swift

How to get row index from UITableView which the array list made by append to a Object Class.
And I want to get the row index based on the value from the object, I needed that for scroll to a row which I only know a value from object, but don't know which the row index.

Below is the code for create a array and show to the UITableView.

```
let paging: Int
let obj: Any
var currentAyaPlaying: Int?
var listArr = [] as [Any]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 700
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.allowsSelection = true

    if paging == Paging.SURA {
        let sura = obj as! Sura
        listArr.append(Sura(sura.index, sura.start, sura.ayas, sura.type, sura.img, sura.name, sura.translate))
        for aya in 1...sura.ayas {
            listArr.append(Mark(sura.index, aya))
        }
    } else if (paging == Paging.JUZ){
        let juz = obj as! Juz
        for suras in juz.sura_start...juz.sura_end {
            let sura = MetaData().mSuras[suras - 1]
            if juz.sura_start == suras {
                for aya in juz.aya_start...(juz.sura_end == suras ? juz.aya_end : sura.ayas) {
                    listArr.append(Mark(suras, aya))
                }
            } else if juz.sura_end == suras {
                listArr.append(Sura(sura.index, sura.start, sura.ayas, sura.type, sura.img, sura.name, sura.translate))
                for aya in 1...juz.aya_end {
                    listArr.append(Mark(suras, aya))
                }
            } else {
                listArr.append(Sura(sura.index, sura.start, sura.ayas, sura.type, sura.img, sura.name, sura.translate))
                for aya in 1...sura.ayas {
                    listArr.append(Mark(suras, aya))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appearNotifAudioReload(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NotifKey.actAudioReloadFromParentToChild), object: nil)
}

@objc func appearNotifAudioReload(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let sura = notification.userInfo?["sura"] as? Int else { return }
    guard let aya = notification.userInfo?["aya"] as? Int else { return }
    print("sura: \(sura)")
    print("aya: \(aya)")
    self.currentAyaPlaying = aya
    if paging == Paging.SURA {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: self.currentAyaPlaying!, section: 0)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    } else if paging == Paging.JUZ {
        let IStackInHere = Mark(sura, aya) // how to get the row index from this data?

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: IStackInHere, section: 0)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listArr.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (listArr[indexPath.row] as? Sura) != nil {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: identifierAyaHeader, bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifierAyaHeader)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifierAyaHeader, for: indexPath) as! AyaCellHeader
        let data = listArr[indexPath.row] as! Sura
        cell.configureWithData(data)
        return cell
    }

    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: identifierAya, bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifierAya)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifierAya, for: indexPath) as! AyaCell
    let data = listArr[indexPath.row] as! Mark
    cell.configureWithData(data)

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (listArr[indexPath.row] as? Mark) != nil {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        let mark = listArr[indexPath.row] as! Mark
        showActionBottom(mark: mark)
    }
}
```

I want to get it in the condition if paging == Paging.JUZ in the func appearNotifAudioReload, I just try to get it with:

```
let index = listArr.firstIndex{$0 === Mark(sura, aya)}
```

But no lucky and error

> "Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and
>   'Mark'"

I know this forum is not to solve my coding problems, but right now I'm really troubled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you receive an error. Can you tell us what the error says?

Comment: "But no lucky and error" <-- what error did you get? What is the error message? Just saying "error" does not tell us much about what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Also, can you post the code for the `Mark` class/struct?

Comment: Hi @Rengers, Mark is struct.

Comment: Hi @Rengers: the error in code line is "Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'Mark'"

Comment: Hi @Sweeper: the error in code line is "Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'Mark'"

Comment: If you want to compare equality, you have to use `==` (two equal signs). But for that to work, `Mark` has to conform to the `Equatable` protocol, and `listArr` has to be of type `[Mark]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `==` (to equal signs) to compare equality. Assuming the Mark struct conforms to `Equatable`, you can use the following:

```
let index = listArr.firstIndex { $0 as! Mark == Mark(sura, aya) }
```

Comment: Hi, now error is: "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Mark' operands"